# Links in pre-form help not showing

Tags: profile

I have a WordPress site running in FR and EN.

I duplicated a profile to be able to have the information in both (pre-form help wasn't allowing dual languages).

In the EN version, a link inserted in the pre-form text shows up just fine. Yet in the FR version, it doesn't show at all. No matter what I do.

I'm puzzled by this behaviour. Any idea where I might start digging to figure it out?

Comment: Does the text in the link appear at all (as plain text), or is the whole link stripped out?

Comment: Can you check if it's a css issue (ie. a css rule that applies only to the fr block) that masks the links? (search on the source for the link or use firebug or the debugger of your browser)

Comment: Can you provide links to your pages?